# Decode JSON single object or array of object dynamically

Tags: json, swift, codable, decodable

Let's say I have an array of JSON response from the GET method like :

```
[{
    "id":"1",
    "Name":"John Doe",
},{
    "id":"2",
    "Name":"Jane Doe",
}]
```

And from the POST method using id param I only have 1 object JSON response :

```
{
    "id":"1",
    "Name":"John Doe",
}
```

how can I write a method to decode both the JSON dynamically?
At the moment, this is what I'm using :

```
func convertJSON<T:Decodable>(result: Any?, model: T.Type) -> T? {
    if let res = result {
        do {
            let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: res, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)                
            return try JSONDecoder().decode(model, from: data)
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return nil
        }
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

The method can be used to decode a single object using dynamic model, but I just can't figure it out to handle a single object / an array of objects dynamically.

> The most I can get with is just using a duplicate of the method but replacing T with
>   [T] in the method parameter and return type, if the response is an array.

I'm open to any suggestion, any help is appreciated, Thank You in advance.

Edit : If this question is duplicate of [this](http://https:/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48739760/swift-4-json-codable-value-returned-is-sometimes-an-object-others-an-array) , I'm not sure how the marked answer could be a solution.

Comment: can you show your model ?

Comment: so you have two methods one is for post and one is for get right ?

Comment: You can just conditionally call your method with parameter like `convertJSON(result: json, model: Model.self)` for single object. And when you need `Array` of object just call `convertJSON(result: json, model: [Model].self)` and it will return `[Model]?` object.

Comment: @Jok3r my model is similar with Aaron answer, and yes there are 2 method

Comment: @nayem that will trigger the " Cannot invoke 'convertJSON' with an argument list of type '(result: Any?, model: [Model.Type])' " error

Comment: Okay. How did you call your method previously?

Comment: I just called it like this : if let device = convertJSON(result: result.value, model: Model.self) { .. }

Comment: And what did you try as per my previous comment for `Array` type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution could be to always return `[Model]?`.

Inside your function first try to decode as `Model`, on success return an array with that single decoded object inside it. If this fails then try to decode as `[Model]`, on success return the decoded object else return nil.

Using your sample JSONs I created a struct:

```
struct Person: Codable {
  let id, name: String

  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id
    case name = "Name"
  }
}
```

Then I created a struct with a couple of methods to decode from either a `String` or an optional `Data`.

```
struct Json2Type<T: Decodable> {
  // From data to type T
  static public func convertJson(_ data: Data?) -> [T]? {
    // Check data is not nil
    guard let data = data else { return nil }
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    // First try to decode as a single object
    if let singleObject = try? decoder.decode(T.self, from: data) {
      // On success return the single object inside an array
      return [singleObject]
    }
    // Try to decode as multiple objects
    guard let multipleObjects = try? decoder.decode([T].self, from: data) else { return nil }
    return multipleObjects
 }

 // Another function to decode from String
 static public func convertJson(_ string: String) -> [T]? {
   return convertJson(string.data(using: .utf8))
 }
}
```

Finally call the method you prefer:

```
Json2Type<Person>.convertJson(JsonAsDataOrString)
```

**Update**: @odin_123, a way to have either a `Model` or `[Model]` as return value can be accomplish using an `enum`. We can even add the error condition there to avoid returning optionals. Let's define the enum as:

```
enum SingleMulipleResult<T> {
  case single(T)
  case multiple([T])
  case error
}
```

Then the struct changes to something like this:

```
struct Json2Type<T: Decodable> {
  static public func convertJson(_ data: Data?) -> SingleMulipleResult<T> {
     guard let data = data else { return .error }
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    if let singleObject = try? decoder.decode(T.self, from: data) {
     return .single(singleObject)
    }
     guard let multipleObjects = try? decoder.decode([T].self, from: data) else { return .error }
     return .multiple(multipleObjects)
 }

 static public func convertJson(_ string: String) -> SingleMulipleResult<T> {
   return convertJson(string.data(using: .utf8))
 }
}
```

You can call it the same way we did before:

```
let response = Json2Type<Person>.convertJson(JsonAsDataOrString)
```

And use a switch to check every possible response value:

```
switch(response) {
  case .single(let object):
    print("One value: \(object)")
  case .multiple(let objects):
    print("Multiple values: \(objects)")
  case .error:
    print("Error!!!!")
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Aaron, using condition is close to what I want to achieve, but the return will always be array, so I'm using Any? instead, and then check the type of the value using if let value = returnValue as? [Model] { .. } after calling

Comment: but is there any way to define return value as either Array of Model or Single Model ?

Comment: Updated to return one value as an enum that may contain: single value, multiple or an error. Hope it helps.