# How can I decode different objects in the same array using Swift Decoder?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am loading a users notifications, there are different notification types (like, comment, follow) and I need to decode each based on their "type" property but I am new to taking this approach and have spent all day trying to figure out how to do this...

Right now I keep getting the decoding error in my NotificationsEnum and I think its because I don't know how to access the **type** property inside each object returned in my array.

I tried using this SO question & answer [Decode JSON from the nested container and check its type dynamically for typecasting in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67195920/decode-json-from-the-nested-container-and-check-its-type-dynamically-for-typecas/67202497#67202497) but it is with classes and  I am using structs.

How can I decode each of these objects based on their type property?? I feel like I need to figure out how to implement **nestedUnkeyedContainer** and **nestedContainer** somehow but I am having a hard time getting this to work.

Also, after getting the decoding to work, how can I put all of these objects in the same array? Would it be a generics since I would switch on their type to route the notifications to different notification views...??

THANK YOU

**Different JSON activity I need to decode depending on type**

```
[
 {
   _id: 61dc9bde82d0715,
   type: 'like',
   username: 'testuser1',
   likeId: 61dcb2d0712
 },
 { 
   _id: 61dc9bde82d0715,
   type: 'follow',
   username: 'testuser2',
   followId: 61dc9bd2d0712
 },
 {
  _id: 61dc9b2d0715,
   type: 'comment',
   username: 'testuser3',
   commentId: 61dc9bb2d0712
 }
]
```

**PROFILE/PARENT DATA MODEL**

```
struct ProfileData: Decodable {
    **otherProperties**
    var notifications: [NotificationsEnum] 
    // ^ Is this correct type? Was thinking I might need some kind of generic array??
}
```

// HOW CAN I IMPLEMENT nestedUnkeyedContainer and nestedContainer here???

```
enum NotificationsEnum: Decodable {
    enum DecodingError: Error {
        case wrongJSON
    }
  
    case like(LikeActivity)
    case comment(CommentActivity)
    case follow(FollowActivity)
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case like = "like"
        case comment = "comment"
        case follow = "follow"
    }
    
   init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        switch container.allKeys.first {
        case .like:
            let value = try container.decode(LikeActivity.self, forKey: .like)
            self = .like(value)
        case .comment:
            let value = try container.decode(CommentActivity.self, forKey: .comment)
            self = .comment(value)
         case .follow:
            let value = try container.decode(FollowActivity.self, forKey: .follow)
            self = .follow(value)
        case .none:
             throw DecodingError.wrongJSON
        }
    }
}
```

**MODELS**

```
struct LikeActivity: Codable {
    let id: String
    let type: String
    let username: String
    let likeId: String
}

struct CommentActivity: Codable {
    let id: String
    let type: String
    let username: String
    let commentId: String
}

struct FollowActivity: Codable {
    let id: String
    let type: String
    let username: String
    let followId: String
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift Decodable with inconsistent API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69910078/swift-decodable-with-inconsistent-api)

Comment: It would be much better if you posted proper json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is to first decode `type` then use a switch over the decoded value and init the corresponding type using the same `decoder` object.

You can also shorten the CodingKeys enum because of this since we are only using one key.

```
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case type
}

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

    let type = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .type)
    switch type {
    case "like":
        self = try .like(LikeActivity(from: decoder))
    case "comment":
        self = try .comment(CommentActivity(from: decoder))
     case "follow":
        self = try .follow(FollowActivity(from: decoder))
    default:
         throw DecodingError.wrongJSON
    }
}
```

You could also create an enum for the `type` values

```
enum ActivityType: String {
    case like, comment, follow
}
```

Then the `switch` in the `init(from:)` becomes

```
switch ActivityType(rawValue: type) {
case .like:
    self = try .like(LikeActivity(from: decoder))
case .comment:
    self = try .comment(CommentActivity(from: decoder))
case .follow:
    self = try .follow(FollowActivity(from: decoder))
default:
     throw DecodingError.wrongJSON
}
```